Why does Bhagavad Gita insult people? Is it original?
BG 9.32

मां हि पार्थ व्यपाश्रित्य येऽपि स्यु: पापयोनय: | स्त्रियो वैश्यास्तथा शूद्रास्तेऽपि यान्ति परां गतिम्

The word "paap yonayah" clearly means born of sin or race of sin since the word yonayah/yoni according to the sanskrit dictionary means race, womb, family, stock, birth etc. So Krishna says here that Vaishya and Shudra varnas are by birth because of past life karma.
BG 4.13

चातुर्वर्ण्यं मया सृष्टं गुणकर्मविभागश: | तस्य कर्तारमपि मां विद्ध्यकर्तारमव्ययम् || 13||

Because 9.32 states that varnas are by birth, the karma resulting in varna referred to here can only be past life karma
BG 1.41-43

अधर्माभिभवात्कृष्ण प्रदुष्यन्ति कुलस्त्रिय: | स्त्रीषु दुष्टासु वार्ष्णेय जायते वर्णसङ्कर: ||(41)|| सङ्करो नरकायैव कुलघ्नानां कुलस्य च | पतन्ति पितरो ह्येषां लुप्तपिण्डोदकक्रिया: ||(42)|| दोषैरेतै: कुलघ्नानां वर्णसङ्करकारकै: | उत्साद्यन्ते जातिधर्मा: कुलधर्माश्च शाश्वता: ||(43)||

Arjun is talking about the pollution (pradushya) resulting in inter-caste people (varna-sankara). In 1.42 he says children of inter-caste marriages create a hellish life and cause the downfall of their dead ancestors. In 1.43 finally he concludes saying caste-dharma and lineage-dharma are both eternal.

All this what Krishna and Arjuna are saying is clearly insulting. Why did they say this?
Is this original - did Krishna and Arjuna really say all this?
How can it be original if it is in Panini's sanskrit?
.

NOTE 1: Someone has seemingly mistranslated "varna sankara" as "unwanted progeny" but the word "varna" is self explanatory and "sankara" in sanskrit
dictionaries clearly means commingling, confusion, mixture,
intermixture etc.
NOTE 2: Someone has also mistranslated "jati dharmah" as "social and family welfare activities" but the word "jati" means caste and "dharma" is self explanatory
NOTE 3: 9.32's fake translation is "whatever their birth, race, gender, or caste" but the words are "paap (sinful) yonayah (race) striyo (women) vaishy (2nd lowest class).. shudr (lowest class)..". This can be verified by old translation or sanskrit dictionary itself.


Truth, knowledge, wisdom, and insight in what ought to be done and not to be done can sometimes by hard to digest.

Btw, "varna sankara" only occurs when the wife belongs to a higher varna than the father.

@Debbie in which book does it say anulom santaan is not varn sankar? Because that's not correct. There are different names for varnsankar anulom children. Example: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122576.html A son begotten by a Brahman father on a Kshatriya mother, is called Murdhabhishikta, while a son by him on Vaishya woman, is called an Amvasta.A son by a Brahmana father on a Shudra woman, is called either a Nishada or a Parvata.... a son begotten by a Kshatriya father on a Vaishya mother, is called a Mahishya  etc.

@Debbie Ramunaja in his commentary seems to see commas between sinful birth and the rest, making it a part of the list. Regardless either way you look at it those people are likely born from previous sins due to which they have certain disadvantages, but the goal of the verse ultimately is to say the lord is the refuge for everyone.

Shudras being the common man tend to be ignorant, Vaishyas deal with wealth making them prone to greed, Women biologically are inferior to men regarding strength and their duty to preform maternal roles may make them less capable of being able to fully invest in divine worship.

I mean either way you look at it to me it makes sense, but also cutting up and cherrypicking a portion of it without looking at it in its whole is wrong. The verse is clearly added with a meaning of inclusivity in Bhakti yoga and not the other way around.

@Haridasa "Ramunaja ... but the goal of the verse ultimately is to say the lord is the refuge for everyone."     Yeah, I know that already.     When I said "Truth, knowledge, wisdom, and insight in what ought to be done and not to be done can sometimes by hard to digest," it was not meant for those who read the Bhagavad Gita, the Ithihasas,  etc holistically.

@Haridasa For instance, I completely believe that the execution of Shambuka at the hands of Lord Ramachandra was justified and that Lord Rama was not a bigot (for instance He was good friends with a nishada name Guha)

@Haridasa My comment "Truth, knowledge, wisdom, and insight in what ought to be done and not to be done can sometimes by hard to digest" was meant to be snarky and sarcastic towards those non-holistic readings of scriptures.

@Debbie you want to take refuge in a lord which calls you of a sinful race? And Raam first asked for Shambuk's jati (75.19) before he decided to chop off his head. When Shambuk replied "shudra yonyam" (76.2) he got killed. This also proved that "yoni/yonah" means race only in this context.

@JaiHo "you want to take refuge in a lord which calls you of a sinful race?" Yes, because He also embraced Guha as a dear friend and devotee, who was born as a Nishad, another "sinful race." So race cannot be a real reason for killing and accepting.

@Debbie So what if he embraced? He didn't teach him Vedas and never called Vidura a Brahmin. Vidura was always Shudra only despite all his knowledge. Because Krishna supported total social inequality - only equality in attaining him. Even in Samba Parva 42.15 he says "like a Sudra failing to obtain the audition of the Vedas" so Krishna was a casteist who doesn't want sinful races to read Vedas................ On Raam - why did the author of that book have to write Raam asked for Shambuk's jati? Why did Shambuk's "shudryonyam" remark get his head chopped off - if he'd only given a different ans

@Debbie he ignored Ramunajacharya's commentary.

@JaiHo Shambuka deserved it the morality then was sensitive he did tapas for his own pleasure without acting in accordance to the sacred tradition then, and he did so for a selfish purpose. Obviously in today's morality such is wrong, but in those days the black and white of morality could clearly be seen in the physical world, so Ram was protecting his Rajyam.

@JaiHo obviously Krishna doesn't want the masses to read the Vedas. The Vedic knowledge in its pure form is highly esoteric and dangerous. Many have misused it and a simple commoner will no doubt fall into the same trap. This is why Puranas and Ithihasas were written. Plus a Vaishya, Kshatryia and Sudra all have rites ascribed to them in Vedic literature the Sudra doesn't, so learning the Vedas would be a waste of time for that Varna.


BG 9.32


मां हि पार्थ व्यपाश्रित्य येऽपि स्यु: पापयोनय: | स्त्रियो वैश्यास्तथा शूद्रास्तेऽपि यान्ति परां गतिम्

Taking a look at how this verse is interpreted by Sri Ramanuja of 11th Century CE. (It is an old interpretation, so no possibility of being influenced by modern ideas).

English Translation By Swami Adidevananda


9.32 By taking refuge in Me even men of evil birth, women, Vaisyas and also Sudras attain the supreme state.


English Translation of Ramanuja's Sanskrit Commentary By Swami Adidevananda


9.32 - 9.33 Women, Vaisyas and Sudras, and even those who are of sinful birth, can attain the supreme state by taking refuge in Me. How much more then the well-born Brahmanas and royal sages who are devoted to me! Therefore, roayl sage that you are, do worship Me, as you have come to this transient and joyless world stricken by the threefold afflictions. Sri Krsna now describes the nature of Bhakti:

In the above interpretation, Sri Ramanuja does not say that Vaishyas/Shudras/women are of evil birth. Instead, he categorizes people of evil birth as a separate group and distinguishes them from Vaishyas, Shudras, women.
There is no insult to anyone here.
Moreover, Bhagavan says this -

विद्याविनयसंपन्ने ब्राह्मणे गवि हस्तिनि।
शुनि चैव श्वपाके च पण्डिताः समदर्शिनः।।5.18।।


English Translation By Swami Adidevananda


5.18 The sages look with an equal eye on one endowed with learning and humility, a Brahmana, a cow, an elephant, a dog and a dog-eater.


इहैव तैर्जितः सर्गो येषां साम्ये स्थितं मनः।
निर्दोषं हि समं ब्रह्म तस्माद्ब्रह्मणि ते स्थिताः।।5.19।।


English Translation By Swami Adidevananda


5.19 Here itself Samsara is overcome by those whose minds rest in equalness. For the Brahman (individual self), when uncontaminated by Prakrti, is the same everywhere. Therefore they abide in Brahman.

Again here, the Gita is saying that men of knowledge treat everyone as equal and they overcome samsaara.

Your translator says - "How much more then the well-born Brahmanas and royal sages who are devoted to me!" 9.32-33 He is basically saying Vaishyas and Shudras are NOT well born, and proving it is by BIRTH only................. so even tho his translation of paap-yonayah is different from most other old commentators, he is another rabid casteist

@JaiHo The Lord is only talking of the prevalent situation at that time. The point is this - if even socially disadvantaged sections are able to reach the Lord easily, then how easier it would be for the socially advantaged sections of the society? There is no casteism here - it's just a reflection on the society structure at that time.

Your translator himself is saying "well BORN Brahmanas and royal sages" in contrast to Vaishyas and Shudras. Keyword is BORN. Ramanuja is also in the minority compared to other traditional translators who all said that paapyonayah referred to women, Vaishyas and Shudras. Is he correct or are the majority correct? It is assumed that the first sentence of the verse is explained by its second sentence. You are just picking and choosing from the minority of translators - who is himself a casteist fanatic

Also no lord is saying this - the sanskrit used primarily follows the grammatical rules laid down by Panini only around the 5th century BCE. Moreover the oldest manuscript is only from the 11th century CE.

@JaiHo The Sanskrit word used is punyayonayoh. Meaning, born in the family that has done punya or good deeds. This does not indicate any casteist mindset prima facie. I am not sure I understand your arguments. If you are also somehow trying to say that the Gita is a 11th century CE work, there is plenty of evidence to show that the Gita existed much before 11th century CE.

@JaiHo Also all that verse is saying is if these people listed as socially disadvantaged can engage in devotion unto me, then what need there be said of these people BORN of their own merits. Yes caste is based on birth all Sruti agree on this. But, the verse in its context is simply further encouraging Arjuna to surrender unto Krishna. Also, your question was why did the lord insult in the sense of sinful birth these other groups? The OP simply stated as per Ramunajacharya sinful birth is an item on a list versus the whole topic.

@JaiHo Lastly Hindu.SE accepts the Vedic and Puranic timeline, so users may not take a historical/indological perspective when writing answers, nor are they obligated to do so. Also, I would suggest you be polite you can certainly to your liking insult gurus and respected personalities, and face the consequences, but this is not the site to do that.

@estimator it is 100% casteist as it means adult people of different varns are either well BORN or of sinful BIRTH. It is talking about adult Brahmins & Rajanyas, not children - so they are adult brahmins BECAUSE they were well born. Krishna has also confirmed Manusmriti elsewhere in Samba Parva 42.15 by saying "like a Sudra failing to obtain the audition of the Vedas." Krishna never said you can change varna and was a total casteist as per current MBH. On historicity I will ask separately and you can answer

@JaiHo This is just a reassertion of your earlier points, not supported by the interpretation of Sri Ramanuja. A casteist moreover never says that one must see brahmin, elephant, dog, dog-eater etc as same. If you have separate questions on casteism in MbH, please ask separately.

Let me put all the referred Slokas of Srimad Bhagvad Gita in their Sanskrit version as well as standard translations in English by authorities:
1. BG 9.32
This sloka is Sri Krishna's response to one of Arjuna's query / doubt)
Sanskrit:
मां हि पार्थ व्यपाश्रित्य येऽपि स्यु: पापयोनय: |
स्त्रियो वैश्यास्तथा शूद्रास्तेऽपि यान्ति परां गतिम् || 32||
English (IAST):
māṁ hi pārtha vyapāśhritya ye ’pi syuḥ pāpa-yonayaḥ
striyo vaiśhyās tathā śhūdrās te ’pi yānti parāṁ gatim
Meaning:
All those who take refuge in Me, whatever their birth, race, gender, or caste, even those whom society scorns, will attain the supreme destination.
2. BG 4.13:
This sloka is Sri Krishna's response to one of Arjuna's query / doubt)
Sanskrit:
चातुर्वर्ण्यं मया सृष्टं गुणकर्मविभागश: |
तस्य कर्तारमपि मां विद्ध्यकर्तारमव्ययम् || 13||
English (IAST):
chātur-varṇyaṁ mayā sṛiṣhṭaṁ guṇa-karma-vibhāgaśhaḥ
tasya kartāram api māṁ viddhyakartāram avyayam
Meaning:
The four categories of occupations were created by Me according to people’s qualities and activities. Although I am the Creator of this system, know Me to be the Non-doer and Eternal.

BG 1.41-43

(These slokas are the doubts raised by Arjuna)
Sanskrit:
अधर्माभिभवात्कृष्ण प्रदुष्यन्ति कुलस्त्रिय: |
स्त्रीषु दुष्टासु वार्ष्णेय जायते वर्णसङ्कर: || 41||
English (IAST):
adharmābhibhavāt kṛiṣhṇa praduṣhyanti kula-striyaḥ
strīṣhu duṣhṭāsu vārṣhṇeya jāyate varṇa-saṅkaraḥ
Meaning:
With the preponderance of vice, O Krishna, the women of the family become immoral; and from the immorality of women, O descendent of Vrishni, unwanted progeny are born.
Sanskrit:
सङ्करो नरकायैव कुलघ्नानां कुलस्य च |
पतन्ति पितरो ह्येषां लुप्तपिण्डोदकक्रिया: || 42||
English (IAST):
saṅkaro narakāyaiva kula-ghnānāṁ kulasya cha
patanti pitaro hy eṣhāṁ lupta-piṇḍodaka-kriyāḥ
Meaning:
An increase in unwanted children results in hellish life both for the family and for those who destroy the family. Deprived of sacrificial offerings, the ancestors of such corrupt families also fall.
Sanskrit:
दोषैरेतै: कुलघ्नानां वर्णसङ्करकारकै: |
उत्साद्यन्ते जातिधर्मा: कुलधर्माश्च शाश्वता: || 43||
English (IAST):
doṣhair etaiḥ kula-ghnānāṁ varṇa-saṅkara-kārakaiḥ
utsādyante jāti-dharmāḥ kula-dharmāśh cha śhāśhvatāḥ
Meaning:
Through the evil deeds of those who destroy the family tradition and thus give rise to unwanted progeny, a variety of social and family welfare activities are ruined.

After having mentioned the original Sanskrit text, IAST transliteration and straight forward meaning in English - it looks obvious, that there is no bias of any kind in the answers given by Sri Krishna to the queries and doubts expressed / presented by Arjuna.
Since the question is mal-formed, and interpretation of slokas is done without any knowledge of Sanskrit language / grammar by the author. The sentence "How can it be original if it is in Panini's Sanskrit?" - itself is an indicator - that the author has no idea of either Sanskrit or Panini's Sanskrit. And this is the reason for Down-Vote by me.
All the applicable references are here:
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/1/verse/41
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/1/verse/42
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/1/verse/43
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/4/verse/13
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/9/verse/32

Please mention the references to whatever you are talking about. My answers are crystal clear, crisp as well as adequate .

@JaiHo Welcome to HSE! The answerer has already supported their opinion with proper citation. If you feel that looks incorrect, you're free to post an answer with authentic sources separately. Unnecessary discussion may not help anyone here.

@TheLittleNaruto thanks - that citation is of a fraud. Many academics are frauds just like Gurus. All sanskrit dictionaries can easily expose this ISKCON translation fraud. Examples: https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=sankar&dir=se and https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/shankara#sanskrit

@JaiHo they've cited proper sources if you find there sources incorrect look at another answer.

@Haridasa how can you call fraud a proper source?? It's not even a translation as some words have been omitted - it's just writing whatever comes to mind

@JaiHo who are you to say what is and isn't a proper source I don't like Isckon, but they're defintely not an inauthentic source.

You need to check the definition of words like "authentic" and "proper" in the English dictionary before you check the Sanskrit dictionary which proves ISKCON's frauds and exposes Prabhupaad @Haridasa

@JaiHo I am aware certain words like Deva have been mistranslated. But, again that's being more nit picky.

Which is why a "word for word" translation is provided for each verse.

Actually, I do remember other Vaishnavas saying what you were, perhaps you are right, but then again most English Translations have flaws it would be better to simply cite the Sanskrit text.
